# Using Mozilla Persona Auth for Single Sign On

Tags: mozilla, browserid

anybody know is possible to use Persona for SSO purposes for cross site login which are sub domains of the single domain ? I do no find this useful feature in documentation.

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If all of the services are within a single domain (e.g. service1.example.com, service2.example.com, etc.), you could set a cookie on the top-level domain directly (example.com) and then all services could use the same session since they would all have access to that session cookie.

So one way to do this would be to redirect users to `login.example.com` when they click the login button on any of the other sites (service*.example.com). That login service would use Persona to ask the user to login and then it would set a cookie on example.com.

This strategy is of course not specific to Persona, it's a common way to get SSO between internal services within a company for example.

Comment: Hello, this solution assumes that there is shared session store on backend and each domain service has access to it, is it ?

Comment: Yes, it does assume a shared session store.If you can't have that, I guess you could simply use Persona on each service. While you technically wouldn't get SSO, your users would still have the ability to sign into each service without typing their email and password on each.